# How to build a raw non-blocking servlet

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0, servlet-3.1

Is there over there a lot of examples about how to create "reactive" services using spring, or whichever microprofile implementation (quarkus, kuuluzee).

According to Servlet 3.1, whichever servlet can be handled as "non-blocking".

I figure out that is mandatory to perform this servlet into a non-blocking servlet container like `netty`...

First question:

- Is it really as I writing? Do I need a non-blocking servlet container implementation in order to make really "reactive" services?

Second question:

- It's not clear to me about how to create a basic raw "non-blocking" servlet. I mean, which would be the difference between a "normal" extending servlet from `HttpServlet`? How would this implementation look like?

Any references?